# Filtering Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, data-cleaning

I've created a dataframe as:

```
ratings = imdb_data.sort('imdbRating').select('imdbRating').filter('imdbRating is NOT NULL')
```

Upon doing `ratings.show()` as shown below, i can see that
the `imdbRating` field has a mixed type of data such as random strings, movie title, movie url and actual ratings. So the dirty data looks this:

```
+--------------------+
|          imdbRating|
+--------------------+
|Mary (TV Episode...|
| Paranormal Activ...|
| Sons (TV Episode...|
|        Spion (2011)|
| Winter... und Fr...|
| and Gays (TV Epi...|
| grAs - Die Serie...|
| hat die Wahl (2000)|
|                 1.0|
|                 1.3|
|                 1.4|
|                 1.5|
|                 1.5|
|                 1.5|
|                 1.6|
|                 1.6|
|                 1.7|
|                 1.9|
|                 1.9|
|                 1.9|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Is there anyway i can filter out the unwanted strings and all just get the ratings ? I tried using UDF as:

```
 ratings_udf = udf(lambda imdbRating: imdbRating if isinstance(imdbRating, float)  else None)
```

and tried calling it as:

```
ratings = imdb_data.sort('imdbRating').select('imdbRating')
filtered = rating.withColumn('imdbRating',ratings_udf(ratings.imdbRating))
```

The problem with above is, since it tried calling the udf on each row, each row of the dataframe mapped to a `Row` type and hence returning `None` on all the values.

Is there any straightforward way to filter out those data ?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Link to the CSV? Does the source itself has this mixed strings in ratings or did the Spark CSV reader misinterpret the data?

Comment: right.. as @Sai said, you must be reading the input data incorrectly which is what introducing random strings into the rating column.

Comment: @Sai Here is the link to the data: https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/imdbmovies

Comment: `imdb_data = spark.read.csv('imdb.csv', header='true')`

this is how i read my data from the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i was able to resolve it.The problem was there was some corrupt data with not all fields present. Firstly, i tried is using pandas by reading the csv files in pandas as:

```
pd_frame = pd.read_csv('imdb.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This skipped/dropped the corrupt rows which had less columns than the actual. I tried to read the above panda dataframe, `pd_frame`, to spark using:

```
imdb_data= spark.createDataFrame(pd_frame)
```

but got some error because of mismatch while inferring schema. Turns out spark csv reader has something similar which drops the corrupt rows as:

```
imdb_data = spark.read.csv('imdb.csv', header='true', mode='DROPMALFORMED')
```